# Help with DB2 Error when trying to execute SQL

Tags: sql, database, db2

I started using the system with a pre-made file called DB2.SQL. I am using this because it is what the tutorial said to use. I then edited this file and replaced the contents with my own code:

```
CREATE DATABASE BANKDB13 BUFFERPOOL BP0;
```

When I try to execute a SQL it though, I get this error:

```
DSNE377A INPUT DATA SET RECFM MUST BE F OR FB WTIH LRECL 80
```

What does this error mean and how do I correct it on the file?
I am running it with Vista TN3270 on Windows 7 over TSO, in SPUFI mode.

What I've tried so far:
When I start editing the file, I have a screen to change the defualts, and I have changed the `RECORD FORMAT` to `F` and `FB` as well as setting the `RECORD LENGTH` to 80 with no success.

EDIT:
I resolved the problem by deleting the DB2.SQL file and recreating it, and also making sure that the sizes I gave for the files were consistent with each other.

Comment: This is not off-topic... It's definitely programming related.

Comment: When you say you modified the file, does this indicate that it was working before your change? If so give more info on the modifications that you've made. Have you altered the file layout so that the records are no longer all the same length? If you need info on record formats check out http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/basics/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.zconcepts/zconcepts_159.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What SQL are you trying to execute on it?

The error means that the Record Format in the input data set must be either "**F** IXED" or "**F** IXED **B**" LOCK with a logical record length of 80.

So this is what the error means, how to correct it depends on the SQL you're running and the desired outcome.

What Tutorial is it that you refer to, do you have a link? Is this a real world problem, homework or you expanding your knowledge into mainframe DB2?

Your SQL snippet above is creating a DB, what is the INPUT DATASET file format that you are subsequently running SQL on?

Comment: It is homework, but I haven't even started it yet because of this problem. I put the whole contents of the file in my question (the first code segment)

Comment: @MadMurf: I don't remember. I've been trying to fix this for a few days.

Comment: I don't think you should be getting that error message just executing  the SQL statement you've provided. It'd be more likely that you'd see an error creating DB or some such. Is there anything else you're leaving out that you're using, any JCL or the like? Also a tip for the future, if changing source files either use local version control or keep a copy of the original.

Comment: @MadMurf: I think the problem is that the the DB2.SQL file that I'm trying to execute doesn't meet those FB and LRECL 80 requirements. Is there a way to change it?

Comment: I never did figure out what was causing it, but I simply deleted and created DB2.SQL file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Interesting, apologies been focused on work stuff for the past few hours